# Running python lines from Atom on Windows

Tags: python, windows, atom-editor

I am trying to set up Atom to be my python IDE. I have seen many Mac users be able to pipe a line into a python shell using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> command, but I have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to set this up.

I have seen packages like script that execute the entire program but am looking for something that can also run python in the shell.

Wondering if anyone is using something like this or has seen something that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question right, but there are two packages which might do (part of?) the job you're looking for:

- [terminal-panel](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-panel)
- [atom-terminal-panel](https://atom.io/packages/atom-terminal-panel)

You can then run a console from within Atom and by customizing keyboard short-cuts, you can probably add the desired functionality.

Comment: I have tried to do this but haven't been able to get a python shell running in either implementation

Answer (score 0):

1)  do u mean {Python Autocomplete Package}?

```
for this purpose u can use package like  {autocomplete-python}, which i am using
```

2)  do u mean run python interactively?

```
for this purpose u can use package {atom-terminal}
```

wish i can help u sth.